# Vue js and dynamic components and content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I want to implement Modal windows in VueJS for my project.
As i always did in jQuery:

- Get HTML of modal via AJAX (HTML is dynamic and backend makes it)
- Append HTML code to BODY

But VueJS has different logic, and i cant really get how to create fully dynamic modal windows.

I can **create Modal window component** and append it to body, but i cant put HTML (that i got from AJAX request) inside component as template slot

```
<slot></slot>.
```

So how can i do that? Maybe some best practices?

Thanks

Comment: Is it *just* HTML you want to render in the body of the modal, or will it potentially contain Vue code?

Comment: @BertEvans Modal window can contain vue components like dropdowns, inputs and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Make the modal element where you want the HTML content to be have the attribute `v-html="modalContent"` and then in your vue code when you want to open that modal make your Ajax request and store the resulting HTML into `this.modalContent`

Comment: i was thinking about but.. Is that good way? Seems like hardcoding.

Comment: And how can i add random quantity of modal windows to page?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

We need to put our modal component outside "#app" with needed html inside (Get it from AJAX) and initiate that instance as new vm.

And create wrapper to manage it like that

```
Modal = { show(), hide(), change() ... }
```

Of course hide method can destroy current modal window VM and whatever.

So after that we will have fully functional modal windows, hope that will help someone else.